# How To Reorder Row in TableView and the Changes Save in the CoreData?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data, tableview

I search already a few days to the answer on the question how can I save the reorder TableView with Swift? So many tutorials on the internet show how to reorder and how to save with Coredata.

This is my code right now. What do I wrong?

Please can you help me to the solution? Thank you very much.

======================================================================

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath)
 { 

     // SecStoredArray = Array name 

     let itemMove = SecStoredArray[sourceIndexPath.row]

     SecStoredArray.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)

     SecStoredArray.insert(itemMove, at: destinationIndexPath.row)

}
```

======================================================================

i'm Using this code for reorder TableView Cell It's Work but I have a one problem The Cell value can't Save In core data Please Any one help me ???????

Comment: You posted hundreds of lines of code with no explanation of what part you are having problems with. You need to explain what your code does, what method(s) you are struggling with, and what is going wrong with your code.

Comment: Duncan gave you the best advice to get a high chance of getting an answer - there are so many lines of code that someone opens this question and might not read everything. I suggest just put the relevant functions where you did some work related to CoreData and reordering. For example `AddButton` function has not no impact on your problem and several other lines of code are similar.

Comment: A database like Core Data saves records unordered. If you need to keep a specific order you have to add an index attribute or something which can be sorted. Of course **you** are responsible for updating the index attribute after reordering the table view.